# android volley response code 500 on registration

Tags: android, post, android-volley

I use volley library to connect to the server. I have login and registration method. They are the same but with different parameters. 
Login method:

```
    private void login(String url){
    RequestQueue requestQueue = MyVolley.getRequestQueue();

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("email", "aubree@wisoky.biz");
    params.put("password", "123456789");
    params.put("person", "0");

    JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url,
            new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    conTV.setText(response.toString());

                    Log.d("Reger", response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    conTV.setText(error.getMessage());
                }
            }){
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(jor);
}
```

And registration method:

```
    private void register(String url){

    RequestQueue requestQueue = MyVolley.getRequestQueue();
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("email", "lork@more.com");
    params.put("password", "123456789");
    params.put("name", "Lurk");
    params.put("surname", "More");
    params.put("person", "0");

    JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url,
            new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    conTV.setText(response.toString());
                    Log.d("Reger", response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    conTV.setText(error.toString());
                }
    }){
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(jor);
}
```

The problem is in registration method logs show this:

> E/Volley﹕ [1608] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://server/api/v1/register

I don't know why? first method work correct but second not.

Comment: look like its server side issue.

Answer (score 6):

As @bharat says, looks like your server is not available. I will recommend you to handle this type of erros like this `onErrorResponse`:

```
        NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
        if (networkResponse != null) {
            Log.e("Volley", "Error. HTTP Status Code:"+networkResponse.statusCode);
        }

        if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
            Log.e("Volley", "TimeoutError");
        }else if(error instanceof NoConnectionError){
            Log.e("Volley", "NoConnectionError");
        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
            Log.e("Volley", "AuthFailureError");
        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
            Log.e("Volley", "ServerError");
        } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
            Log.e("Volley", "NetworkError");
        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
            Log.e("Volley", "ParseError");
        }
```

Comment: how can it be anything else but ServerError, since the server responded with a valid answer (albeit an error)? This will not give any more information

Comment: By the response code 500 we already know it is a server error. but how to solve it, that's what we are looking for. I am getting same error even though postman is working, on android studio i get error.

Answer (score 0):

i faced this problem too and i found that my server side had no permission for a specific included file in the main link .. 
try to access your server developer to give you the needed permissions